# django - auto populating the fields in the models

Tags: django, django-models

Please have a look at my models.py.

models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    pass

class ThreadParticipant(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class MessageReadState(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    read_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I am having two problems when I try to create a new message:

1. How do I auto populate the Thread with its primary key whenever I create a new message, without manually creating a new thread?
2. How to create a new user if the user is not in the the ThreadParticipant, or else don't create a new user?

I think I can solve this all in the views.py, but I think it will be better to solve this in the models.py. Please help me solve the problem. I would be very grateful. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Suppose, I need to create a new message. The steps will be:

1. I will have to create a new `Thread` first.
2. And similarly, I will have to create a new `ThreadParticpant` for that Thread (`pk`).
3. I will have to get that user who sent the message to create a new user (participant) for that `ThreadParticipant`.

So my problem is, when I try to create a new message, I don't want to go and create a new thread first or create a new set of ThreadParticipants. I just want it to be on the background, so that all I have to do is create a message and send it to the user. Hence, my questions are:

1. How do I create a new Thread in the background automatically and use its pk for the `ThreadParticipant`?
2. So, if the `ThreadParticipant` has its new Thread to relate, how do I get the user who sent the message and create a new user for that set of thread participants?

Can it be done by overriding the save method or class method?

Comment: Your `thread_pk` field is redundant. Django creates `id` fields automatically (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Comment: Yes, I think i will remove it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're attempting to achieve? I can't quite work out what you mean.

Comment: I am sorry, let me elaborate a little more. I have edited the question, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st question, I believe you should use [F](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture/wiki/Documentation#fixture-f) function of [django-dynamic-fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture).
And for 2nd question, use this `User.objects.get_or_create(conditions)`